# Shorthand check if variable isset or not and echo them to value of input field

Tags: php

i want to check in the shortest way, if a variable exists (to prevent e-warnings...) or not and echo a value to a input field.

I trie to do it with the in PHP 7 possible way,but it wont work for me. Maybe i have a bug in my little code?

That it is:

```
$mycontent='<input type="text" name="myfield" class="form-control" 
value="'.isset($post['myfield']) ? $post['myfield'] : ''.' " 
id="myfield">';
```

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use brackets round your `isset()` condition

```
$mycontent='<input type="text" name="myfield" class="form-control"
    value="'.(isset($post['myfield']) ? $post['myfield'] : '').' "
    id="myfield">';
```

or you can use [null coalescing operator (??)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)...

```
$mycontent='<input type="text" name="myfield" class="form-control"
    value="'.($post['myfield'] ?? '').' "
    id="myfield">';
```

Comment: the null coalescing operator is awesome

Comment: But of course you wouldn't want to do this if the array is unfiltered/unescaped.  Try something like: `htmlspecialchars($_POST['foo'] ?? '')`.